# itertools.ifilter with IPython Parallel

Tags: python, ipython, generator, python-itertools, ipython-parallel

For some problem [proven to be NP hard] I have no other option but exhaustive search. I have a set of data — for simplicity, `S = ['A', 'B', 'C', ... ,'Z']` and want to apply a function `f` to all subsets of length `N < len(S)` of this set.  I cannot use lists here since binomial coefficients `binom(len(S),N)` are some billions. But the result of `f(x), x∈S` is zero for *almost all* the values of `S`. Therefore in simple cases all works great with

```
   from itertools import ifilter, combinations
   answer = list(ifilter(lambda x: f(x) > 0, combinations(S,N)))
```

But in real life, `len(S) ~ 10⁴` and `N ~ 10²`. What I want is to spread the work among CPU engines using `ipyparallel`. I have a small cluster with a hundred of CPU cores. But I still cannot afford to store combinations as lists, therefore I need something like separate generators.

There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527006/split-a-generator-into-chunks-without-pre-walking-it) of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915170/split-a-generator-iterable-every-n-items-in-python-splitevery) of how to split generator into chunks, but as far as I understand they are still *consecutive* generators. There is also an [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18168705/4222580) of @minrk that is related but it performs really bad for some reason.

So the questions are:

- is there any way to implement `itertools.ifilter` directly with `ipyparallel`? *or*
- is it possible to separate python generator into a set of *independent* generators (to send them to `ipcluster` engines independently)?

Answer (score 1):

Exhaustive search is utterly hopeless here, no matter how you parallelize it. With `len(S)` and `N` at such high orders of magnitude, you would need to search through about 6e241 solution candidates. This is far beyond the capacity of any computational system humanity could ever hope to build.

You will need to use a smarter algorithm.